# Running 2 internet explorers on one taskbar? IE 11, Windows 10

Tags: internet-explorer, taskbar

I work for a company that shall remain unnamed. We have clients and use 2 separate websites to service and maintain their accounts.

What I would like is to have 2 separate internet explorer icons on my task bar, so that only windows (and subsequent tabs) opened from that shortcut appear when I hover over that shortcut.

Is this something that is possible? We have to use IE per company policy so using a different browser isn't an option.

Comment: Whether the behavior was fixed in 7, or added in 10, Windows 10 no longer behaves as that linked question describes. This is not a duplicate.

Comment: Question body made no mention of what OS. Title and tag is important but honestly I only read the question body.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open IE and browse to one of the sites you manage.
2. Click the gear icon to open the settings menu.
3. Click **Add site to Apps**.
4. Click Add. The site icon is now in the taskbar.
5. Right-click on the new icon on the taskbar and click **Pin to taskbar** to keep it from disappearing when you close the browser window.

This site now has its own icon in your taskbar. When you open this site from this icon on your taskbar, and then open subsequent tabs in this browser window, these will show beneath this icon on your taskbar.

Repeat these steps for the other site.